# Cannot Manage Flash Drive

Tags: windows-10, permissions, usb-flash-drive, format, chkdsk

I have a brand new Kingston DTSE9 64GB flash drive formatted as exFAT.  I was able to use the flash drive at home on my Dell laptop (64 bit Windows 10, Administrator), so now it has some files on it.

Now, I am on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine at work where I am logged in using my domain account.  My account has administrator privileges, and belongs to the 'Administrators' group.  The flash drive will let me copy files from it, but nothing else.  I cannot copy files to the drive, where it tells me that 'You need permission to perform this action.', even though I am an administrator.  I cannot run a CHKDSK, where it tells me 'Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges.', even though I am running the command prompt as an administrator (using right-click, 'Run as Administrator').  It also tells me the same thing when I attempt to use TAKEOWN or ATTRIB.  Using PowerShell does not fix the problem, and disabling UAC does not fix the problem either.  The latest drivers are all installed.

However, I am able to do everything I need to in Safe Mode, but formatting it in Safe Mode and then attempting to use it after a reboot still presents the same issues.

How can I get my flash drive to work normally?

[image: Attempting to Copy a File]

[image: Attempting to Run a CHKDSK]

Comment: @EugenRieck this is not an answer or helpful

Comment: @Skyler Sedate First, have you checked with your IT dept, they have removable storage locked down, even with admin rights. Second, it is possible that Windows is not recognizing it as a removable device and loading the correct driver, try going to Device Manager and uninstall the driver, remove the drive, and reinsert it.

Comment: @acejavelin The obvious answer to "How can I get my flash drive to work normally?" is to upgrade your operating system to one, on which root is root.

Comment: @EugenRieck No, that is not a valid answer, the drive is compatible with Win10 and should work. Changing OS should be the very last resort for something that should, and can, work properly in the current environment.

Comment: @acejavelin Found out that the corporate IT policy disallows the write ability to external USB devices.  So while this question can technically be closed, I am curious as to how that works exactly.  Is it like a registry value?

Comment: @acejavelin - turns out it definitly IS a windows issue!

Comment: @EugenRieck: ...and installing a different OS on a work computer is most likely **not** an option. Get real.

Comment: @EugenRieck No, it not a Windows issues, it is a corporate security policy issue. A properly installed Linux [insert distro name here] installation would register with the domain and enforce the same policies. This is not a private computer, which in turn technically makes this off-topic as well.

Comment: There is no scenario, in which a sane OS would deny privileges to root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a corporate IT policy, disallowing the write privilege to USB drives.